# Does Node.js's npm provide cryptographic authentication and integrity validation?

Tags: authentication, integrity, node.js, package-manager, npm

Does Node.js's `npm` package manager cryptographically validate its payload's authentication and integrity for all packages after downloading them and before installing them?

I see a lot of guides providing installation instructions with steps asking the user to install Node.js dependencies with `npm install ...`. I usually don't do this as I trust my OS package manager (ie `apt`) to actually validate the origin/trust and integrity of the package before installing it.

Does `npm` provide cryptographic authentication and integrity checks for all items downloaded before installing them by default?

Note: Transport validation via X.509 does not count as a valid auth/integrity check.